# Add a heading to list of conditional array of Jekyll posts

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I've got a simple loop of my Jekyll posts which I've conditionally limited to just those posts  which have myvalue set to true:

```
<ul>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
       {% if post.myvalue == true %}    
        <li><a href="{{post.url}}">{{ post.title }}</a>
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If none of the posts have myvalue set to true, then the list should not appear.

My question is: how do I add a heading above my list to also conditionally display along with this list without having it appear inside the loop? I.e. how do I check if ANY of my posts have myvalue set to true so that I can display the heading once? What I'm after:

The final output if myvalue = true in any of my posts:

## My heading

- Post 1
- Post 2

The final output if myvalue = false:

Nuthin!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% assign has_myvalue = false %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
   {% if post.myvalue == true %}    
      {% assign has_myvalue = true %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if has_myvalue %}
    Here's some output because a post had myvalue==true
{% endif %}
```